# Add p element after $(this) in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a `p` element after `$(this)`. I have wrote this `$(this).p.addClass("abc");`
But it is not working. How can i do this?

Comment: Could you post your code here. I'll review.

Comment: You're trying to add a `p` element, or add a class to an existing `p` element?

Comment: You should face the jQuery-pointers, you always select the hole subclass. $('p') will select all p-elements, not only a subclass. You can handle this, when you use a class like myClass: $('p.myclass').

Comment: add a class to an existing p element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(this).after('<p></p>').addClass('abc');
```

see doc for [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

if you want to add a class to the `<p>` coming just after `$(this)`, then

```
($this).next('p').addClass('abc')
```

or maybe just (from your comment)

```
$(this).addClass('selected');
```

or

`$(this).find('p').addClass('selected');`

you may also want toggleClass, see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvkdP/)

Comment: Actually , my gold is to add a class to p . like this  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.span').click(function(){
      
                   $(this).p.addClass("selected");
      
     
    
   });
   
  
      
    
   
  });

Comment: do you mean `($this).next('p').addClass('abc')` then ?

Comment: @user1531622 well what is .span ? A class of your p ?

Comment: @user1531622 well try my last update, maybe, then. If you mean :  `<span class="span"><p>asdf</p></span>` and you wanna update the inner p. It would be easier if you gave some sample html code !

Comment: <div class="span2">
<a href="#"><i class="icon-compass icon selected"></i>
       <p>Featured</p>
</a>
     
</div>
<div class="span2">
<a href="#"><i class="icon-fire icon"></i>                          <p >News</p>
</a>
</div>                                                                                                                                       $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.span2 ').click(function(){
      
     $(this).p.addClass("selected");
      
     
    
   });
   
  
      
    
   
  });

Comment: Thanks. It is  working  . solved the problem by $(this).find('p').addClass('selected');

Comment: @user1531622 fine. Next time, try to put some code in your question, it helps to solve misunderstanding problems ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/):

```
$("<p>text to insert </p>").insertAfter(this);
```

Comment: @CodyGuldner No it doesn't. This works just fine. `$("<p>text to insert </p>")` creates a `<p>`, and then inserts it after the `this` element

Comment: I want to add a class to p when i will click to the parent of p

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way

```
$( this ).after( "<p class='abc' />" );
```